# Does PWA works well on the Magento Commerce Cloud with the UPWARD connector?

Tags: pwa, pwa-studio, magento2-cloud, magento-cloud, upward

There is a Magento 2 UPWARD connector module to keep Magento and storefront code on the same server. Has anyone used PWA Studio storefront in the Magento Commerce Cloud? Is this connector reliable?

https://github.com/magento-research/magento2-upward-connector